# Using MySQLdump for sub-set of database migration

Tags: select, import, mysql

I've been using both mysql and mysqldump to teach myself how to get data out of one database, but I consider myself a moderate MySQL newbie, just for the record.

What I'd like to do is get a sub-set of one database into a brand new database on a different server, so I need to create both the db/table creation sql as well as populating the data records.

Let's say my original db has 10 tables with 100 rows each.  My new database will have 4 of those tables (all original columns), but a further-refined dataset of 40 rows each.  Those 40 rows are isolated with some not-so-short SELECT statements, one for each table.

I'd like to produce .sql file(s) that I can call from mysql to load/insert my exported data.  How can I generate those sql files?  I have HEARD that you can call a select statement from mysqldump, but haven't seen relevant examples with select statements as long as mine.

Right now I can produce sql output that is just the results set with column names, but no insert code, etc.

Assistance is GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, not sure if I should add additional data here or down below, so kind of repeating myself:

Started down that route, but my SELECT is very long and throws errors when I try to run it from the command prompt. So... can I make mysqldump read the SELECT from a stored file?

Answer (score 9):

You will probably have to use mysqldump to dump your tables one at a time and using the where clause

**-w, --where='where-condition'**

```
Dump only selected records. Note that quotes are mandatory:
"--where=user='jimf'" "-wuserid>1" "-wuserid<1"
```

For example:

```
mysqldump database1 table1 --where='rowid<10'
```

See docs: http://linux.die.net/man/1/mysqldump

Comment: Started down that route, but my SELECT is very long and throws errors when I try to run it from the command prompt.  So... can I make mysqldump read the SELECT from a stored file?

Answer (score 1):

mysqldump each table with a where clause like Dennis said above.  one table at a time and merge the scripts with cat

```
cat customer.db order.db list.db price.db > my_new_db.db
```